# How to troubleshoot Axis 2 Error

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have created a WSDL and I wanted to make use of AXIS 2 as my web server.

I downloaded it into my C:\axis2-1.6.1 and set all the required installation parameters.

My question is, I deployed my *.aar file into the repository/services folder and the axis2server
was able to decompressed it and I see my web service when I navigate into the

http://localhost:8080

When I used SOAPUI to test my service, I am only getting this error.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>unknown</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Not sure but I do not see any error on the Axis console?

Where can I find any relevant info to solve this problem?

Comment: Tricky. I have never used that application server. Can you connect the Eclipse debugger to it and then add an exception breakpoint for Exception or Throwable, then reproduce your error? Or maybe if you have the axis source you can figure out the code part which throws a fault and put a breakpoint in there. I take it you're not planning to use that web server in production, though, otherwise if you get errors like this in live systems you're in trouble. You really need it to dump out useful stack traces.

Answer (score 7):

This link contains a couple of pieces of advice on configuring axis to include stacktraces in the fault message:

http://www.mail-archive.com/axis-user@ws.apache.org/msg41600.html

In case it gets removed, here's Keith Chapman's suggestion reproduced:

> Try setting these two parameters in your axis2.xml

```
<parameter name="sendStacktraceDetailsWithFaults">true</parameter>
<parameter name="DrillDownToRootCauseForFaultReason">true</parameter>
```

It's not a replacement for knowing where your error output is going, but it may help with the immediate problem.

Comment: it's useful for me to find the problem.