# JAX-WS webservice operation failing after disabling SSLV3

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, jax-ws

We are trying to consume Webservice, which was working earlier but now for each of the operation it's failing and getting following SOAP response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>unknown</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

We are using Tomcat and using Java6. Recently we disabled SSLV3, after that we are facing this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to troubleshoot Axis 2 Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783234/how-to-troubleshoot-axis-2-error)

Comment: SOAP-ENV:Server -- There was a problem with the server, so the message could not proceed.

Comment: Recently we disabled SSLV3, after that we are facing this issue.